# Improving Global Scene transition when changing location using bookmarks in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: performance, rendering, windows-7, arcgis-pro, global-scene

Using ArcGIS Pro 1.0.0 I have:

1. Created a new project using Global Scene.aptx
2. Switched the Basemap to National Geographic
3. Navigated to and created Bookmarks for some countries of different sizes: Australia and Singapore
4. Used the project's Options to set the Transition Time to 2.0 seconds on the Navigation tab
5. Used the Bookmarks to navigate alternately between Australia and Singapore

I expected that doing this would result in a display cache being created that would mean no re-rendering and a very smooth display during transition.

However, each time I use a bookmark to go to the other country there are a few seconds of blurry re-rendering that occur.

Are there settings available that should assist me to get the result I describe as expected above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just retested this using a later version of ArcGIS Pro and, while I think the software behaviour is the same, I have been experimenting with the project's Options to set the Transition Time on the Navigation tab to values of 0.0, 2.0 and 5.0 seconds.

The longer transition times exacerbate the "blurry effect" described in the question, and by setting it to 0.0 seconds that effect is minimized.

Consequently, I am going to use a Transition Time of 0.0 seconds.